# Sending response in async function

Tags: express, asynchronous, async-await, request

I need to return an array of labels, but I can only return 1 of the labels so far. The error which I get is "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". So I tried res.write and placed res.end after my for loop then I get the obvious error of doing a res.end before a res.write. How do I solve this?

```
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
request.get(arr[i], function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    myfunction();
    async function myfunction(){
    const Labels = await Somefunctioncallwhoseresponseigetlater(body)
    res.send(Labels);
}
}
});}
```

New code-

```
    async function getDataSendResponse(res) {
    let allLabels = [];
    for (let url of arr) {

        let body = await got(url).buffer();
        var imgbuff= Buffer.from(body,'base64')
        const imageLabels = await rekognition.detectLabels(imgbuff);
        allLabels.push(...imageLabels);
    }
    res.send(allLabels);
}
```

The error I have with this code is

"Resolver: AsyncResolver

TypeError: Cannot destructure property `Resolver` of 'undefined' or 'null'."

Comment: Also, please be clear about whether your question is now resolved or whether something is still not working.

Comment: No the question hasn't been resolved yet

Comment: Where is the error coming from?  From what line of code?  What NPM module does `rekognition.detectLabels()` come from?  Or is it your own code?

Comment: No, it's AWS Rekognition API. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectLabels.html

Comment: Can you provide one of the URLs that you query to get these images?

Comment: I'm hosting this on a Local host. and the query is just an array of URLs. 

`localhost:3000/submit?array[]=www.google.com&array[]=www.amazon.com`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `res.send()` inside a `for` loop.  That means you'll be trying to call it more than once.  You can't do that.  You get to send one response for any given http request and `res.send()` sends an entire response.  So, when you try to call it again inside the loop, you can the warning you see.

If what you're trying to do is to send an array of labels, then you need to accumulate the array of labels first and then make one call to `res.send()` to send the final array.

You don't show the whole calling context here, but making the following assumptions:

1. `Somefunctioncallwhoseresponseigetlater()` returns a promise that resolves when it is done
2. You want to accumulate all the labels you collected in your loop
3. Your `Labels` variable is an array
4. Your http request returns a text response.  If it returns something else like JSON, then `.text()` would need to be changed to `.json()`.

then you can do it like this:

```
const got = require('got');

async function getDataSendResponse(res) {
    let allLabels = [];
    for (let url of arr) {
        let body = await got(url).buffer();
        const labels = await Somefunctioncallwhoseresponseigetlater(body);
        allLabels.push(...labels);
    }
    res.send(allLabels);
}
```

Note, I'm using the `got()` library instead of the deprecated `request()` library both because `request()` is not deprecated and because this type of code is way easier when you have an http library that supports promises (like `got()` does).

Comment: I get an error saying "TypeError: Cannot destructure property `Resolver` of 'undefined' or 'null'."

and my http request returns an image

Comment: @bigdaddy-zephyr - We need more details to provide exact working code.  This should show you the proper structure - you can perhaps modify it to fit your specific data.  If you want further help, then please show the code for `Somefunctioncallwhoseresponseigetlater(body)` and share an example URL that you are making a request from and getting back an image.  I need to be able to see exactly what that response looks like and exactly what data input that function is expecting.

Comment: @bigdaddy-zephyr - FYI, you can change the `.text()` to `.buffer()` to get binary data from your http request, but I would need the info I asked for in the previous comment to help further.

Comment: ` async function getDataSendResponse(res) {
  let allLabels = [];
  for (let url of arr) {
    let body = await got(url).buffer();
    var imgbuff = Buffer.from(body, "base64");
    const imageLabels = await rekognition.detectLabels(imgbuff);
    allLabels.push(...imageLabels);
  }
  res.send(allLabels);
} `

Comment: @bigdaddy-zephyr - Is this your working solution in the comment above?  Or are you asking a question about that?

Comment: No since you needed to know which function I was using I pasted the code in the comments. Made changes in the original question for readability.

Comment: @bigdaddy-zephyr - Did this help you get an answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.